# Is graphene a combustible material?

Tags: combustion, materials, reactivity, carbon-allotropes

Various sources such as https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7679154 speculate that graphene will combust at higher temperatures.

Is this true? Is the flash point/ temperature of combustion for graphene known?

Comment: Graphene is not a material at all, to begin with.

Comment: I would hardly consider that link a "source"...

Comment: The Wikipedia article for graphene links to a Journal Phys. Chem abstract claiming that it combusts around 350 C. I have no access to the full article with the specific details.

Comment: Graphene is a name for rather diverse materials (size, purity, concentration of defects etc can be different, occasionally stabilizers) so actual behavior may vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graphene combusts at 620 K. See http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp410044v.

It is postulated that it burns at this temperature "because of a large interlayer spacing of graphene sheets (i.e., 5.1 Å)".

Answer (score 1):

As @airhuff pointed out, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene) of graphene says that graphene combusts at 350℃. This statement is taken from [another link](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp410044v) which states  as to why graphene combusts:

> it(graphene) has a high specific surface area of ca. 1168 m2 g–1 and
>   **starts to burn at 350 °C because of a large interlayer spacing of graphene sheets (i.e., 5.1 Å).**

Answer (score -2):

Graphene is made from carbon atoms, just like diamond and graphite. 
Just like diamond and graphite, it will burn in oxygen.